# Clickable images in JS request

Tags: javascript

Since we are talking about setInterval, clickable objects do not work. I do, however, have an SVG on the page that displays an additional div using jQuery. It would be important to make this image clickable after my query.

```
<script>
const intervalId = setInterval(function() {
  const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://example.com/abc.php");
  xhttp.send();
  contentLoaded = true;
}, 6000);
</script>
<div id="table"></div>
```

The process of clicking on the SVG contained in abc.php:

```
<img id='svg' src='https://example.com/image.svg' class='svg'>
$('#svg').click(function() {
  var text = '<?php echo $text; ?>';
  $.post("https://example.com/def.php", {get-php: true, text: text, function(data) {
    alert(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Is that JavaScript code inside a `<script>` tag or is it just dumped in there as shown?

Comment: Not sure `{get-php:true` is valid JavaScript syntax.